# Unable to merge rasters

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have several rasters that I want to merge but after selecting the layers, in the raster > misc > merge tool, the panel window just closes without any error and of course no new merged raster has been created. I tried with both qgis3.10 and 3.12 and the SAGA Mosaic raster layers as well. With no success, nothing happens.

Comment: Please add more information on the rasters you're trying to merge (size, CRS, data type, naming) as well as your input into the GUI dialogues.

Comment: Well... I'm on Mac and actually, after selecting the layers, the merge panel window, for some reason, goes behind the main qgis window... so it becomes invisible.

Comment: Have you tried resizing the main window so you can access the merge window?

Comment: Yes that's what I did. But it's pretty annoying.

Comment: Can you start the merge-process after resizing?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine.

Comment: Could please update your question accordingly?